# react-bootstrap form button doesn't submit on first click

Tags: reactjs

The form only makes the api call (submits the form) on the 2nd click. Is it the way Im using async for the arguments? Is there something wrong with my function?

Handler Function:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchAllImages(keyword);
  };

  const searchAllImages = async (keyword) => {
    const response = await searchImages(keyword);
    setImagelinks(response.data.message);
    const imageObjects = imagelinks.map((link, index) => {
      let newImage = {
        url: link,
        id: index,
        fav: false
      };
      return newImage;
    });
    setImages(imageObjects);
  };
```

Form:

```
<Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" controlId="keyword">
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="keyword"
              value={keyword}
              onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Search a Dog"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
        <Button type="submit" className="button">
          Search
        </Button>
      </Form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so when you do `setImagelinks(response.data.message);`, `ìmagelinks` still not equal to `response.data.message` when you `map` on it the line below,

Try to do `response.data.message.map` instead like this :

```
const imageObjects = response.data.message.map((link, index) => {
      let newImage = {
        url: link,
        id: index,
        fav: false
      };
      return newImage;
    });
```

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted if it's ok for you, thank you